# contact sensor: how to get the force information

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, All,
I am working on add a contact sensor on a link, and I want to get the torque of the joint of this link, now I meet some question:

1. `msgs::contacts` contacts, the order, I cannot find the member function 'contacts' of msgs, where can find the definition of `msgs::contacts`, and what type Variable is the contacts ? and how can I use its member function or events?
2. when I use the

   ```
   function:unsigned int c = parentSensor->GetCollisionContactCount(const string&test_collision3)
   ```

an error will appear:

```
    ContactPlugin.cc:56:57: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
```

how to solved it? and other function including `const` appear this error too.

1. I want to input the data of sensor in a `.txt` file, how can I do it?
2. where can the document define the relationship between the sensor `plugin.so` and the `plugin.cc`, in `CMakelist.txt` or in the `.world` file? because I want to add 3 contact sensors to 3 links, so the plugins must be Distinguished.

thanks a lot

best
gdlu

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1167/contact-sensor:-how-to-get-the-force-information/) by [lugd1229](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/79/lugd1229/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 75 on 2013-02-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2013-02-06**:
please post your code in your question.  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Here's another example of how the information from a force torque sensor is simulated in drcsim:

- first, [get the lFootContactSensor](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/45a23d87af80af8bbc467a58382dba903f8572d7/ros/atlas_msgs/AtlasPlugin.cpp?at=default#cl-185), next,
- [connect lContactUpdateConnection to sensor updates](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/45a23d87af80af8bbc467a58382dba903f8572d7/ros/atlas_msgs/AtlasPlugin.cpp?at=default#cl-407), and,
- Structure your [OnLContactUpdate callback like so](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/45a23d87af80af8bbc467a58382dba903f8572d7/ros/atlas_msgs/AtlasPlugin.cpp?at=default#cl-633).

Alternatively, there is [a ticket to implement a ForceTorqueSensor class](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/379/create-a-force-torque-sensor), which may simplify this process.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lugd1229](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/79/lugd1229/) on 2013-02-06**:
thank you, but how to solve the question 2:                                                           function:unsigned int c = parentSensor->GetCollisionContactCount(const string&test_collision3)

an error will appear:

ContactPlugin.cc:56:57: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’

how to solved it? and other function including const appear this error too.

**Comment by [lugd1229](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/79/lugd1229/) on 2013-02-06**:
and I set the updatetime is 1 second , then there are 58 groups(contacts size)* 14 groups (position size) data, what difference between the contacts and the positions data?

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2013-02-06**:
A message may contain contact from multiple time steps, in this case, you have 58 groups, or 58 simulation time steps has occurred before the last contact message.  Within each contact group, the number of contact joints actually generated by collision detection and solved by the physics engine is reflected by its position_size (14 in your example)

**Comment by [lugd1229](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/79/lugd1229/) on 2013-02-11**:
if I want to obtain the realtime data and draw the figure of the link's torque along the time, how can I deal with the data?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-02-13**:
It's easiest to handle realtime data through a plugin. You can write a sensor or model plugin that process contact sensor data every iteration.